# Wrong autocompletion with sudo apt-get

Tags: apt, bash, sudo, aptitude, auto-completion

Does anybody know why if I type:

```
apt-get upg<TAB>
```

I get:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

but if I type:

```
sudo apt-get upg<TAB>
```

I get:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade-from-grub-legacy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Some time ago, trying to make `bash-completion` work also for `sudo`, I added:

```
complete -cf sudo
```

to my `.bashrc`. Commenting it out makes my `sudo apt-get` autocomplete correctly.